# Objective C - Touch detection

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an image gallery section for an app.
How can I detect a tap with a little delay? Just like how the Photos app is doing to toggle between hiding the navigation and showing the navigation?

This is the method that I'm using now

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

It works just fine, however, the tap and the swiping of the image is making the app look confused. Like, I intend to swipe, but the tap will kick in too.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement all three methods, smth like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _touchMoved = NO;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _touchMoved = YES;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( !_touchMoved ) {
             // good we just tapped!
             // here you can also check for time difference between when touches began and ended
    }
}
```

However if "Long Press" is what you are looking for, then consider using gesture recognizers, specifically `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. You can create an instance of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, and attach it to your view by using `-(void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` defined on any `UIView`